# Java 8 streams: find items from one list that match conditions calculated based on values from another list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Have two classes and two corresponding lists:

```
class Click {
   long campaignId;
   Date date;
}

class Campaign {
   long campaignId;
   Date start;
   Date end;
   String type;
}

List<Click> clicks = ..;
List<Campaign> campaigns = ..;
```

And want to find all `Click`s in `clicks` that:

1. Have a corresponding `Campaign` in `campaigns` list, i.e., `Campaign` with the same `campaignId` AND
2. This `Campaign` has `type` = "prospective" AND
3. This `Campaigns.start` < `click.date` < `Campaigns.end`

So far I have the following implementation (which seems confusing and complex to me):

```
clicks.
        stream().
        filter(click -> campaigns.stream().anyMatch(
                campaign -> campaign.getCampaignType().equals("prospecting") &&
                        campaign.getCampaignId().equals(click.getCampaignId()) &&
                        campaign.getStart().after(click.getDate()) &&
                        campaign.getEnd().before(click.getDate()))).
        collect(toList());
```

I wonder if there is simpler solution for the problem.

Comment: I think all you really need to do is extract that larger lambda into a named method.

Comment: @JoeC is this really possible? This lambda refers to both click and campaign which means I will need to use BiPredicate while filter accepts Predicate

Comment: `click -> checkCampaigns(click, campaigns)`

Comment: Regardless of (perceived or real) elegance of stream-based solutions: I'd **strongly** suggest to use an **algorithmically** different approach. The `anyMatch` may seem handy, but has O(n), so for `m` clicks and `n` campaigns, this is O(nm). Building a `Map<ID, Campaign>` to use as a lookup would change this to O(n+m) (possibly supported by some `TreeMap` for indexing by the date, but that may be a second step)

Comment: By the way, the troublesome `Date` class has been supplanted by the [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.  Avoid `Date` where possible, but where you must you can convert using new method added to the old class: [`myDate.toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that stands out is that your 2nd requirement has nothing to do with the matching, it's a condition on `campaigns` only. You'd have to test if this is any better for you:

```
clicks.stream()
    .filter(click -> campaigns.stream()
        .filter(camp -> "prospecting".equals(camp.type))
        .anyMatch(camp -> 
            camp.campaignId == click.campaignId &&
            camp.end.after(click.date) &&
            camp.start.before(click.date)
        )
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Otherwise, I have never seen a streams solution which does not involve streaming the 2nd collection inside the predicate of the 1st, so you can't do much better than what you did. In terms of readability, if it looks that confusing to you then create a method that test for the boolean condition and call it:

```
clicks.stream()
    .filter(click -> campaigns.stream()
        .filter(camp -> "pre".equals(camp.type))
        .anyMatch(camp -> accept(camp, click))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

static boolean accept(Campaign camp, Click click) {
    return camp.campaignId == click.campaignId &&
            camp.end.after(click.date) &&
            camp.start.before(click.date);
}
```

Finally, 2 unrelated suggestions:

1. Don't use the old `Date` class, instead use the new [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)'s [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).
2. If `Campaign`'s `type` can only have some predefined values (like "submitted", "prospecting", "accepted"...) then an `enum` would be a better fit than a general `String`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, there is a very neat way to solve your problem IMO, original idea coming from Holger (I'll find the question and link it here).

You could define your method that does the checks (I've simplified it just a bit):

```
static boolean checkClick(List<Campaign> campaigns, Click click) {
    return campaigns.stream().anyMatch(camp -> camp.getCampaignId() 
               == click.getCampaignId());
}
```

And define a function that binds the parameters:

```
public static <T, U> Predicate<U> bind(BiFunction<T, U, Boolean> f, T t) {
    return u -> f.apply(t, u);
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
BiFunction<List<Campaign>, Click, Boolean> biFunction = YourClass::checkClick;
Predicate<Click> predicate = bind(biFunction, campaigns);

clicks.stream()
      .filter(predicate::test)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That's indeed neat, but the OP said they find their current solution "confusing and complex", so I can't imagine this one being less so.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents:
Since there is no much boilerplate code in OP. So it may be not possible/necessary to reduce the lines/characters in the codes. we could rewrite it to make it a little more clearly:

```
Map<Long, List<Campaign>> map = campaigns.stream().filter(c -> c.type.equals("prospecting"))
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.campaignId));

clicks.stream().filter(k -> map.containsKey(k.campaignId))
               .filter(k -> map.get(k.campaignId).stream().anyMatch(c -> c.start.before(k.date) && c.end.after(k.date)))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code is not much shorter than original code. but it will improve performance from O(nm) to O(n+m), as @Marco13 mentioned in the comments. if you want shorter, try [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
Map<Long, List<Campaign>> map = StreamEx.of(campaigns)
                .filter(c -> c.type.equals("prospecting")).groupingBy(c -> c.campaignId);

StreamEx.of(clicks).filter(k -> map.containsKey(k.campaignId))
        .filter(k -> map.get(k.campaignId).stream().anyMatch(c -> c.start.after(k.date) && c.end.before(k.date)))
       .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Click> findMatchingClicks(List<Campaign> cmps, List<Click> clicks) {
    List<Campaign> cmpsProspective = cmps.stream().filter(cmp -> "prospective".equals(cmp.type)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return clicks.stream().filter(c -> matchesAnyCmp(c, cmpsProspective).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public boolean matchesAnyCmp(Click click, List<Campaign> cmps) {
     return cmps.stream().anyMatch(click -> cmp.start.before(click.date) && cmp.end.after(click.date));
}
```

Replace fields for getters, just wrote it quick.